# External google search link open in browser

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2.1

I want to open the google search link like 'https://www.google.co.in/#q=adam+scott' in sencha touch hybrid ios app. I tried to use var ref = window.open(url, '_blank','location=yes'); but it is not loading the page and if I change the _blank to _system it is loading the page but not showing done button to move to previous page.

Please let me know if some body has done it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

navigator.app.loadUrl('https://www.google.co.in/#q=adam+scott', { openExternal:true } );

Answer (score 0):

open your MainViewController.m class and add this line of code before @end

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
    }
}
```